# PHPExcel: long numbers have scientific format (xxxE-08) when reading

Tags: php, phpexcel

When reading an Excel file with PHPExcel Reader, long numbers are printed out in scientific format, so `0.0000000123` becomes `1.23E-08`.

The documentation says I can avoid this with `Advanced Value Binder`, but unfortunately this only works with CSV files.
Also `setReadDataOnly()` does not help.

It also happens if the cell is formatted with long floating numbers so it is displayed as `0.0000000123` in Excel.

There are some topics here for *writing*, but not for *reading*.

Question: How do I fetch the number w/o scientific format?

Answer (score -1):

Just came across the idea, that PHP is responsible for echo scientific notation, so I have tried `number_format($var, 8);` and it worked.

So it's not PHPExcel. I have to echo using `number_format`.